# Java unexpected type error

Tags: java

Below is a piece of code of a game in an applet.I got the error:
unexpected type 
required  variable found value.
Actually the error is because of my assignment in method repaint but how should it be?
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public class subclass of JApplet{
    JApplet jp; 
    int yPos=230;
    public void check{

        if(jp.getX()>160 && jp.getY()<200)
            repaint();
    }

    public void repaint(){
        jp.getX()=jp.getWidth()-10;
        jp.getY()=yPos;
    }
}
```

Comment: `public class subclass of JApplet` and then `JApplet jp`? Please submit compilable code, or at least code without artificial errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem reside in these two lines :

```
jp.getX()=jp.getWidth()-10;
jp.getY()=yPos;
```

I assume that `getX` and `getY` return some `x` and `y` variable. However, you can't mutate them that way, you need to create a setter method or acces them directly and modify them.

Something like :

```
public void setX(int x)
{
    this.x = x;
}
```

Then you would do

```
jp.setX(someValue);
```

or if the field is not private you could directly do :

```
jp.x = someValue;
```

The error message "required variable, found value" refer to what is returned by `getX`. The left side of an assignment must be a variable to hold the value, but in your case it is a value (returned by the getter) hence the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a value to a method call.  Change `repaint()` to something along the lines of:

```
jp.setX(jp.getWidth()-10);
jp.setY(yPos);
```